# I am having a problem parsing this json using python

Tags: python, json

Code that is suppose to display each stock's price:

```
    def holdings():
        holdings = r.account.build_holdings()
        for stock in holdings:
            print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Draco = AutoTrader | {Fore.RED}{stock["price"]}')
```

This is what the "holdings" variable displays:

```
{'IBIO': {'price': '2.530000', 'quantity': '68.00000000', 'average_buy_price': '1.9216', 'equity': '172.04', 'percent_change': '31.66', 'equity_chan'quantity': '46.00000000', 'average_buy_price': '16.0093', 'equity': '577.76', 'percent_change': '-21.55', 'equity_change': '-158.667800', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'American Airlines', 'id': '45ccb9d7-b9f0-40aa-833f-8381a4e5c3e5', 'pe_ratio': None, 'percentage': '43.82'}, 'BIOC': {'price': '0.840000', 'quantity': '100.00000000', 'average_buy_price': '0.8299', 'equity': '84.00', 'percent_change': '1.22', 'equity_change': '1.010000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Biocept', 'id': '7081b018-8dd3-4599-8ab3-178398f64cd8', 'pe_ratio': None, 'percentage': '6.37'}, 'CMCSA': {'price': '43.540000', 'quantity': '5.70093400', 'average_buy_price': '42.8000', 'equity': '248.22', 'percent_change': '1.73', 'equity_change': '4.218691', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Comcast', 'id': '1db76c1d-74b6-46a3-a1e5-c58ab489d5c2', 'pe_ratio': '17.550100', 'percentage': 
'18.82'}, 'AGS': {'price': '4.130000', 'quantity': '33.55882900', 'average_buy_price': '4.4698', 'equity': '138.60', 'percent_change': '-7.60', 'equity_change': '-11.403290', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'PlayAGS', 'id': '488b9fb3-5ac2-4618-9c32-e2bd639b8ced', 'pe_ratio': None, 'percentage': '10.51'}, 'PACD': {'price': '0.282000', 'quantity': '300.00000000', 'average_buy_price': '0.3978', 'equity': '84.60', 'percent_change': '-29.11', 'equity_change': '-34.740000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'PACIFIC DRILLING', 'id': '6bccc808-9210-4ce7-aaac-1be56a1c1c4b', 'pe_ratio': None, 'percentage': '6.42'}}
```

I want to access each stock and price but I keep getting this error:

```
    print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Draco = AutoTrader | {Fore.RED}{stock["price"]}')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Why are the function and variable names the same? Won't that variable assignment replace the function at least locally?

Comment: Where's "this json"?

Comment: I really don't see it. And judging by the number left of my comment, at least one other person also doesn't. I also don't see any parsing attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only iterating over the keys. Use `dict.items()`:

```
for stock_name, stock_vars in holdings.items():
    print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Draco = AutoTrader | {Fore.RED}{stock_vars["price"]}')
```